# php and xps files

Tags: php, xps

i only want to import the content as text but im getting the binary values, tried something like but its doesnt work:

```
$data = file_get_contents("input.xps");
```

theres any lib that i can use?
thank you

Comment: what are you trying to do with the data? XPS is Microsoft's post script format (kind of like PDF), so it makes sense that you're seeing binary data and not text.

Comment: just want to get all the text from it, i dont care about images, tables,...

Comment: XPS files are uncommon and might be unfavourable for you to work with. Are there other formats that you can use?

Comment: only if i could convert the xps file to another one and then parse it..but all the tools i tried didnt worked (like xps to pdf = images)

Comment: From what I can see, there doesn't seem to be a library for reading postscript files in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a tool that can convert .xps files. There is a GhostScript variant called `gxps` which does exactly that. http://ghostscript.com/GhostXPS.html

Conversion to text would be a two step process with it, but still simple:

```
exec("gxps -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=input.pdf -dNOPAUSE input.xps");
$text = exec("pdftotext input.pdf");
```