# How to read from Xps file using php

Tags: php, xps

Hi i need to retrive all the information from xps file using php can any one one knows please inform to me its urgent..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968464/php-and-xps-files - might help

Answer (score 1):

You have to know that XPS is just PKZIP format, containing some XML-files as descriptions and other stuff as document content.
So your task is just to extract .zip into one temp folder, grab .xml and analize.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool that can convert .xps files. There is a GhostScript variant called gxps which does exactly that.

```
http://ghostscript.com/GhostXPS.html
```

Conversion to text would be a two step process with it, but still simple:

```
exec("gxps -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=input.pdf -dNOPAUSE input.xps");
$text = exec("pdftotext input.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Farahan Dharsi , i tried this but i dont get the output . Is there any other way ..?